# what is the difference between 1 and '1'?

Tags: sql

I've got a column named FLAG in a table A and its value can be either 1 (one) or 0 (zero).

The results for the below two [SQL] queries are the same.

CODE 1

```sql
SELECT ID
FROM A
WHERE FLAG = 1
```

CODE 2

```sql
SELECT ID
FROM A
WHERE FLAG = '1'
```

Please explain the difference between `1` and `'1'`.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is relating to the rules regarding SQL Server identifiers. Pls check out documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @learning - single quotes always denote strings, not identifiers. SQL Server supports delimited identifiers using double quotes or square brackets, neither of which is present here.

Comment: Column Flag data type?

Answer (score 1):

1 is of type integer
'1' is of type string

You can write 1 + 1 and a system will output 2. If you write '1' + '1' then the system will add the two strings together to form '11'.